# How to convert boost::multiprecision::int512_t to boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float_100?

Tags: boost, double, precision

I'm using boost::multiprecision recently. My code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp>

namespace bm = boost::multiprecision;

int main(void) {
    bm::int512_t a = 12;
    bm::cpp_dec_float_100 f = a;

    std::cout << f * 3.14 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It didn't compiled. Error shows:

```
b.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
b.cpp:9:28: error: conversion from ‘boost::multiprecision::int512_t {aka boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_int_backend<512u, 512u, (boost::multiprecision::cpp_integer_type)1u, (boost::multiprecision::cpp_int_check_type)0u, void> >}’ to non-scalar type ‘boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float_100 {aka boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_dec_float<100u> >}’ requested
  bm::cpp_dec_float_100 f = a;
                        ^

How can I convert it correctly? Thanks a lot!
```

Comment: `f=static_cast<bm::cpp_dec_float_100>(a);` seems to work. I have no idea if it's correct or not.

Comment: @cv_and_he I have tested, it's right!

Answer (score 0):

I new to this stuff myself but I've been using boost multi_precision quite a lot,
I imagine the below should work

bm::cpp_dec_float_100 f = bm::cpp_dec_float_100 f(a);